# Prevent flip while scaling a group of objects in fabricjs

Tags: fabricjs

Is there any way to prevent flip while scaling group of objects?

I tried 'lockScalingFlip' attribute. But it is only supported while scaling a single object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check with `object:scaling` if flipX or flipY are true ... If they are then the object has been flipped so you will have to set it again to false.

canvas.on('object:scaling', onObjectScaled);

```
function onObjectScaled(e){
    var scaledObject = e.target;
    console.log(scaledObject.flipX);
    if(scaledObject.flipX == true || scaledObject.flipY == true){
        scaledObject.flipX = false;
        scaledObject.flipY = false
    }
}
```

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rt72gg6t/) to see it in action

Answer (score 6):

In version 1.4.11, set `lockScalingFlip=true` should work.

Comment: Can you update your question and add link to change log, ticket in issue tracking system, or other resource explaining why/how the setting works for group instead of single object? Without it it's more of a comment rather than a complete answer.

Comment: Works perfectly in version 4. Using it globally with ```fabric.Object.prototype.lockScalingFlip = true;```